# Tweepy Bad Authenticaton Data

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to make a Twitter bot using the Tweepy 3.6 with Python 3.6. For now I just want to try connect my Twitter account with this piece of code :

```
# Add all import statements at top of file
from src.credentials import *
import tweepy

if __name__ == '__main__':

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    api.update_status('test')
```

But I have this error message :

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]
```

I check the permissions of my app, it's on Read/Write. And I also double check all the credentials to be sure I didn't do some mistakes in here

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried to type directly credentials in code ? like "auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('xxxxx', 'xxxxx')", maybe there is a problem with import

Comment: I reload all my keys in the apps.twitter.com website and all works great :)